# how to do column-wise mean centric, unit varience matrix normalization in python

Tags: python, pandas

how to perfome  column-wise mean centric, unit varience matrix normalization in python with given data.

```
GA_ID   PN_ID   PC_ID   MBP_ID  GR_ID   AP_ID   class
0.033   6.652   6.681   0.194   0.874   3.177     0
0.034   9.039   6.224   0.194   1.137   Nan       0
0.035   10.936  10.304  1.015   0.911   4.9       1
0.022   10.11   9.603   1.374   0.848   4.566     1
0.035   2.963   17.156  0.599   0.823   9.406     1
0.033   10.872  10.244  1.015   0.574   4.871     1
0.035   21.694  22.389  1.015   0.859   9.259     1
0.035   10.936  10.304  1.015   0.911   Nan       1
0.035   10.936  10.304  1.015   0.911   4.9       1
0.035   10.936  10.304  1.015   0.911   4.9       0
0.036   1.373   12.034  0.35    0.259   5.723     0
0.033   9.831   9.338   0.35    0.919   4.44      0
```

I used this method:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
raw_data = open("data.csv")
dataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:5]

X_pro = preprocessing.scale(X)
print X_pro
```

This is the out come of the above code: Now how can i verify wither my data has been normalize by columns and has  mean = 0 and variance = 1 or not.

```
[[-0.1167218  -0.63345757 -1.07300641 -1.48050718  0.21992262]
 [ 0.16341052 -0.1357136  -1.18055612 -1.48050718  1.47958828]
 [ 0.44354283  0.25985419 -0.22037492  0.65725579  0.39713794]
 [-3.19817727  0.08761434 -0.38534723  1.59203886  0.09539293]
 [ 0.44354283 -1.40269826  1.39216468 -0.42594688 -0.02434715]
 [-0.1167218   0.24650873 -0.23449523  0.65725579 -1.21695837]
 [ 0.44354283  2.50314269  2.6236912   0.65725579  0.14807857]
 [ 0.44354283  0.25985419 -0.22037492  0.65725579  0.39713794]
 [ 0.44354283  0.25985419 -0.22037492  0.65725579  0.39713794]
 [ 0.44354283  0.25985419 -0.22037492  0.65725579  0.39713794]
 [ 0.72367515 -1.73424954  0.18676073 -1.07430617 -2.7256834 ]
 [-0.1167218   0.02943647 -0.44771194 -1.07430617  0.43545477]]
```

Comment: This seems to be the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249749/how-can-i-transformed-descriptors-mean-centered-and-scaled-to-unit-variance-prio) except with less description, and still no example output (do you want the normalization done on the entire column or after filtering by class?).

Comment: @DSM I have updated my Question, with the out put.

Comment: Are you asking how to get means and variance by column? if, yes `X_pro.mean(axis=0)` and `X_pro.var(axis=0)` will output those by column.

Comment: @Primer that i know and its mean and variance is not as per my expectation (mean = 0, variance = 1)